# How to trigger and find status of sql job through c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, etl

I have an requirement in which SQL server job needs to be trigger through C# and show the status in web application from its start to end.

SQL server job has to fetch data from excel file and loading it to the SQL Server 2008 R2 database which has minimum of 25000 rows and maximum of any.

Please help in resolve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. Have you already searched for [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568512/how-to-invoke-the-job-in-sql-server-agent-from-windows-application)?

Comment: I have tried like getting the status of the job and displaying it in web page.My requirement is like to showing the status continuously from start to end of the job.For that,I have called the timer event after enabling the job from button.In timer event,I tried to monitor the status of the job.