# Using an Integration services project within a Windows Form or WPF app?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis

I am trying to make an application to display and add up some data in excel sheets but using a SQL server. The gist of the app is that i can use a windows form or WPF to choose a directory path and select an excel file. Then the app loads the excel data into a SQL table (using Integration services project) where I can then query the data to display the necessary information.

My question is how do i incoperate this excel sheet import into a Windows form. I am able to create a Integration Services project and create my SQL table but i want to be able to load an excel file into SQL from my windows form.

Any direction would be much appreciated. I assume I have to do something to get my package out of the Integration Services Project and into my WindowsForm or WPF project.

Thanks!

Comment: Do be aware of the licensing implication. Wherever you have Integration Services is running is going to require that machine be licensed for SQL Server. That's either 8k Std or 22k Enterprise per core for current book listings. If it's a straight shot of Excel to SQL Server, as much as I love SSIS, skip it. Just use the [OLE/ACE driver to query excel like a database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990184/181965) and use a Table Valued Parameter to push it all to SQL Server at once instead of singleton inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a windows form created almost exactly like this but its way too much code to show.  It connects to an excel you select, connects to sql db, pulls sql db into excel, modifies excel data.

Edit:  Posted on github for anyone to use.

https://github.com/tshoemake/ProductivityReport

Comment: Is there any chance you could put it on github or email it to me or something? I've been looking for a solution to this all day

Answer (score 0):

You can try to integrate the SSIS project into SQL Server (SQL Server standard and Up with Integration Services required). You can integrate it into a SQL Server Job like this video explains [Deply SSIS Package to SQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdxOxHM5Ijw) and then call the job from your code in you app like this link describes [Call SQL Server job from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568512/how-to-invoke-the-job-in-sql-server-agent-from-windows-application)

Good Luck